# Convert string column into characters rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a table that contains following data:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | P126 |

And I need to convert this table into

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | P |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 6 |

I tried `STRING_SPLIT`, but it is not working for empty delimiter.

Can someone please help me to format the data?

Answer (score 8):

You can solve this by using a recursive cte:

```
DECLARE @t nvarchar(10) = 'P126';

WITH cte AS (
SELECT 1 id, LEFT(@t, 1) col, RIGHT(@t, LEN(@t)-1) txt
UNION ALL
SELECT id+1, LEFT(txt, 1), RIGHT(txt, LEN(txt)-1)
  FROM cte
  WHERE LEN(txt) >= 1
)
SELECT id, col
  FROM cte
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this like:

```
declare @str as varchar(2048) = 'P126'

;with c0 as(
select @str as s
), c1 as(
select number as n from master.dbo.spt_values where type = 'P' and number > 0
)
select SUBSTRING(c0.s, c1.n, 1) as item
       , ROW_NUMBER() over(order by c1.n) as pos
       , c0.s
from c0
inner join c1 on c1.n <= LEN(c0.s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create table and insert values:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test3](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [value] [varchar](20) NULL
)

insert into [dbo].[test3] values (1,'P126');
```

**Solution 1:**
We can pass the value from the table to the variable `@t` via select query.

```sql
DECLARE @t nvarchar(10);
select @t=value from [dbo].[test3];

WITH cte AS (
SELECT 1 id, LEFT(@t, 1) col, RIGHT(@t, LEN(@t)-1) txt
UNION ALL
SELECT id+1, LEFT(txt, 1), RIGHT(txt, LEN(txt)-1)
  FROM cte
  WHERE LEN(txt) >= 1
)
SELECT id, col
  FROM cte
```

**Solution 2:**
We can define a function.
Create a function to split string:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

create function [dbo].[MySplitStringFunc]( @str nvarchar(100)) 
returns @tableName Table 
  ( 
    id int identity(1,1),
    value nchar(1) 
  ) 
as  

begin 

  declare @insertStr nvarchar(100)
  declare @newstr nvarchar(100)
  declare @id int
  set @id=1;
  set @insertStr = substring(@str,@id,1) 
  set @newstr = stuff(@str,@id,1,'')
  begin
    insert @tableName Values(@insertStr) 
  end
  while(len(@newstr)>1)
    begin 
      set @id =@id + 1
      set @insertStr = substring(@str,@id,1) 
      insert @tableName values(@insertStr) 
      set @newstr = stuff(@newstr,1,1,'') 
    end 
    
  insert @tableName values(@newstr) 

  return
end
```

Call the function and it returned a table:

```sql
declare @string nvarchar(100)
select @string=value from [dbo].[test3] 
select * from [dbo].[MySplitStringFunc](@string)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi@Mojo Jojo If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you. : )